# Disable hostname verification in c# httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, ssl, hostname

I'm implementing web services in a c# environment. I'm using a SSL connection. My url is seomthing like:

```
https://pseudoservername:8443/services/...
```

But the certificate expects it to be:

```
https://ourcompany.services.public.com:8443/services/...
```

So I got a hostname mismatch. In Java you can simply turn off this hostname verification by making your own hostnameVerifier class and letting the JVM use that one instead of the normal one. This is really useful because the effect are only local (only disable verification for this application) and temporary (hostnameverification can be turned on/off whenever the application wants to).

How can do you this is in c#?

I do not want a solution where the entire certificate validation is ignored. I also want to preserve the local & temporary effects of disabling the hostnameverification. I do also not want change my url (to just make them match) for reasons beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using WebRequests or something similiar, you can hook into the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`
and add a custom validation scenario as

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
            Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, 
            SslPolicyErrors errors)
            {
                if (errors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)
                {
                  return (true);
                }
                else
                {
                  return (false);
                }
            };
```

see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details

Comment: I specifically said in my question I do not want to disable my certificate checking by simply returning true on every check. I ONLY want the validation to ignore the hostnames of the certificates. How can I do this?

Comment: As stated, you can use this to implement a custom validation, e.g. check for errors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

Comment: My apologies, I overlooked the name of the exception!  (I thought it was a general exception)

Comment: It was in the first Version of the answer, the specific check for a RemoteCertificateNameMismatch was added after your comment

Comment: I succesfully implemented a solution by checking the errors asyou described, bounty awarded! Just an additional note: SslPolicyErrors is a flagged enum, meaning I also had to check for: "case (SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)" and others.