# How to create and use a DNS-based self-signed certificate on different networks

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate

I have the following code to create a self-signed certificate:

```
SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder subjectAlternativeNameBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
subjectAlternativeNameBuilder.AddDnsName("TestSRV01);
X500DistinguishedName x500DistinguishedName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN=Self-Signed-Test");
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
{
    var certificateRequest = new CertificateRequest(x500DistinguishedName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));        
    certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(new OidCollection { new Oid("2.5.29.32.0"), new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }, false));
    certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(subjectAlternativeNameBuilder.Build());
    var certificate = certificateRequest.CreateSelfSigned(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(3650)));
    return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Export( X509ContentType.Cert, pw), pw, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
}
```

I only add the DNS name of the server *to avoid the binding to the current IP address* (the test machine is moved around different networks).

As it turned out, I need to use the IP address when I connect from the client (DNS resolving is unreliably on the test site).

Unfortunately, the SSL connection fails with this message:

> (Hostname 192.168.0.*** not verified:
>       certificate: sha256/UuUOTTQTCb2wu************************
>       DN: CN=

I can't bind the certificate to this address, but I also can't use the domain name as the connection parameter.

Can I create a usable certificate around this problem? Or should I modify the cert values whenever the computer boots up and add the current IP address to is `SubjectAlternativeName` list?

Comment: If DCHP is used on Network your code will be even less reliable since the IP address routinely change with DCHP.  IP address uses IP routing and if the masks are not configured properly you will not find the host.  Why do you think DNS is unreliable?

Comment: @jdweng DNS resolving on site tends to fail (the DHCP is running on a server instead of a router), so I try to use the current IP address. Is there a better solution than updating the certificate?

Comment: DCHP is suppose to run on a Server.  Usually the same server as the Network Password Server.  It is probably failing due to a timeout.  The certificate should be on a Proxy Server and IP only set once.

Comment: @jdweng It is a special case, the certificate is on the test machine and it has lots of IP changes. So I have to figure out how to bypass the IP and let the connection be established.

Comment: Do not use IP addresses in HTTPS URLs, this will not work like you expect.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Should I rely on the fact that no matter what LAN the server is located at, there will be DNS resolving?

Comment: Nowadays without name resolution not a lot of things can work at all... And if DNS resolution fails in some spot, this has to be fixed, trying to go around that. will only create other problems down the road.

Comment: What client are you using to connect, and how are you attempting to connect?

Comment: @JamesKPolk The cliens are mobile phones, using .Net Standard HttpClient instances, and I connect via `SendAsync` methods.

Comment: Ok, so they require that the hostname in the URL must match one of the SubjectAlternativeNames. In that case, what does the hostname part of the client URL look like?

Comment: @JamesKPolk The URLs don't contain any of the hostname, they are consisting of IP addresses right now. That is the main problem as the server certificate doesn't containt those addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments it seems the best way to handle this case is to provide custom certificate verification in the clients, bearing in mind the caveats in Patrick Mevzek's comments.

Custom certificate verification involves you writing your own code to verify certain aspects in the certificate. The [`HttpClientHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netframework-4.7.1) class provides a 
`ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` property that you can set with your own callback.

The certificate is evaluated first by .NET and then the results of this validation are passed to your callback as an [`SslPolicyErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslpolicyerrors?view=netframework-4.7.1) enum along with the certificate. You have several options for correcting the validation error(s). See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22193673/238704) for a hint. Inside the callback you can examine the subject alt name in the hint and make sure it is "TestSRV01".

The [`GetNameInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.getnameinfo?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_GetNameInfo_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509NameType_System_Boolean_) method of [`X509Certificate2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=netframework-4.8) can be used to retrieve only the first DNS name in the list of subject alternative names, so if the hostname you want to check is not the first one then you'll have to do battle with .NET to get the information you need.

Comment: What does this mean? That if I return from the callback `true` based on a custom hostname check, the SSL connection is established? Or does it mean that the SSL connection isn't established but the error is ignored and a _regular_ connection is established?

Comment: If you return true the SSL connection is established, if you return false it isn't. There is no "regular" connection, with an https url it is all or nothing, either the connection succeeds and you have ssl or the connection does not succeed and you have  nothing.

Comment: I think I go along with this solution, as I can check whether the host name is what the client stores. Unfortunately, I use a custom `HttpMessageHandler` and its `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` is never hit so I use the global `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. Strangely, the `cert` argument is always null, I only get the `message` and `chain` and `errors` argument.

Comment: Cert is null? That doesn't sound right. Unfortunately my .NET expertise is limited.

Comment: It was `null` because I used a custom handler, and it somehow couldn't load it.