# Needing assistance with DSE C# driver configuration over SSL

Tags: ssl, cassandra, datastax-csharp-driver

Having trouble configuring a DSE C# driver to use SSL. I have spun up my own DSE Cluster with one node and node to node encryption as well as client to node encryption turned on. No errors! However below is a small code that I am using to test a that i can connect to the cluster with SSL.

```js
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection collection;
            using (var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                collection = store.Certificates;
            }

            var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
                .AddContactPoints("192.168.14.11")
                .WithCredentials("cassandra","cassandra")
                .WithSSL(new SSLOptions().SetCertificateCollection(collection))
                .Build();

            ISession session = cluster.Connect();

            global::System.Console.WriteLine("test");

        }
    }
```

I keep receiving the following error when it gets to the session:

"Dse.NoHostAvailableException: 'All hosts tried for query failed (tried 192.168.14.11:9042: AuthenticationException 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.')'"

I also imported both the nodes and cacert into my machines local.

On the cluster side it throws the following error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: Cerrtificate_unknown.

Comment: can you try to disable hostname validation? It's often a primary reason for error

Comment: @AlexOtt Hi Alex thank you for getting back to me. I am uncertain as to how I can disable host name validation?

Comment: you can combine this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884001/disable-hostname-verification-in-c-sharp-httpwebrequest) with example of setting verification callback in the https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.13/features/tls/#certificate-store

Comment: Ive tried it before and it fails at the RemoteCertificateNameMismatch level. I checked the CN on the cert and it matches the hostname on the node. @AlexOtt

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not the C# expert... Just tried to help based on my experience with Java & other languages. You can ask here: https://community.datastax.com/ - there is a big chance that somebody from dev team will answer